# Yii 2 JS assets minification prolem

Tags: php, yii2, bundle, assets, minify

I recently installed Yii 2.0.6 and I noticed that it loads

```
yii.js
yii.validation.js
yii.activeForm.js
```

from **yiisoft/yii2/assets** folder, so I wanted to overwrite these files and in **common/config/main.php** I added these lines of code but what it does is that it replaces only yii.js file but yii.validation.js and yii.activeForm.js keep being loaded.

```
'assetManager' => [
            'forceCopy' => YII_DEBUG,
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\YiiAsset' => [
                        'js' => ['all.min.js'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

How can I replace all those files by a single one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also disable `ActiveFormAsset` and `ValidationAsset` :

```
'bundles' => [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset' => [
        'js' => ['all.min.js'],
    ],
    'yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset' => false,
    'yii\validators\ValidationAsset' => false,
],
```

Read more : [Customizing asset bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles) or [Combining & compressing assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#combining-compressing-assets)

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#combining-compressing-assets) :

> 1. Find all the asset bundles in your application that you plan to
>      combine and compress.
> 2. Divide these bundles into one or a few groups. Note that each bundle
>      can only belong to a single group.
> 3. Combine/compress the CSS files in each group into a single file. Do
>      this similarly for the JavaScript files.
> 4. Define a new asset bundle for each group:
>
>    - Set the css and js properties to be the combined CSS and JavaScript files, respectively.
>    - Customize the asset bundles in each group by setting their css and js properties to be empty, and setting their depends property to be
>        the new asset bundle created for the group.

So you need to use a tool to compress your files then you inject each to its adequate bundle :

```
'assetManager' => [
'bundles' => [
    'all' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetBundle',
        'basePath' => '@webroot/assets',
        'baseUrl' => '@web/assets',
        'css' => ['all-xyz.css'],
        'js' => ['all-xyz.js'],
    ],
    'A' => ['css' => [], 'js' => [], 'depends' => ['all']],
    'B' => ['css' => [], 'js' => [], 'depends' => ['all']],
    'C' => ['css' => [], 'js' => [], 'depends' => ['all']],
    'D' => ['css' => [], 'js' => [], 'depends' => ['all']],
],
```

See [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#combining-compressing-assets) for more info.